# Response time of two messages in the same chat

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, response, sql-date-functions

**The scenario**

A chat_channel can have multiple MESSAGE_ID which is displayed on separate rows.

```
INSERT INTO messages_tbl 
            (message_id, 
             chat_channel, 
             user_type, 
             message_type, 
             message_custom_type, 
             msg_created_on) 
VALUES      ('00001', 
             'chat_1', 
             'consumer', 
             'msg', 
             'example message', 
             '2018-09-27 10:14:42'); 

INSERT INTO messages_tbl 
            (message_id, 
             chat_channel, 
             user_type, 
             message_type, 
             message_custom_type, 
             msg_created_on) 
VALUES      ('00002', 
             'chat_1', 
             'merchant', 
             'msg', 
             'example message', 
             '2018-09-27 11:14:42');
```

With this example I would like to compare and calculate a response time from the first message sent from the consumer to the second message sent by the merchant. This data about the time and date is the column MSG_CREATED_ON.

I am able to do the calculations but struggling as their on different rows. I have tried partitioning them on CHAT_CHANNEL but are having no luck..

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 8.0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below would be one way -

```
SELECT t1.chat_channel, 
       Timestampdiff(minute, t1.msgcreated_on, t2.messagecreated_on) 
FROM   (SELECT chat_channel, 
               Min(msgcreated_on) time1 
        FROM   message_tbl 
        WHERE  t1.user_type = 'CONSUMER' 
        GROUP  BY chat_channel) t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT chat_channel, 
                          Min(msgcreated_on) time2 
                   FROM   message_tbl 
                   WHERE  t1.user_type = 'MERHCANT' 
                   GROUP  BY chat_channel) t2 
               ON t1.chatchannel = t2.chatchannel
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using MySQL 8+, we can make use of the analytic functions.  Here is one approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CHAT_CHANNEL, MSG_CREATED_ON,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_TYPE ORDER BY MSG_CREATED_ON) rn
    FROM MESSAGES_TBL
)

SELECT
    t1.CHAT_CHANNEL,
    t1.rn AS conversation_number,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.MSG_CREATED_ON, t2.MSG_CREATED_ON) AS diff_in_minutes
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.CHAT_CHANNEL = t2.CHAT_CHANNEL AND
       t1.rn = t2.rn AND
       t1.USER_TYPE = 'consumer' AND
       t2.USER_TYPE = 'merchant'
```

I use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign a common value to each individual paired exchange between and a consumer and merchant, for each chat channel.  Then, I join together on the chat channel and the conversation being the same.